# List or single line array/parameters: Does one or the other perform better?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

A little bit of a generic question but it has been playing on my mind for a while.

Whilst learning php coding, to help me create a WordPress Theme from scratch, I have noticed that some arrays/parameters are kept to a single line whilst others are listed underneath one an other.  Personally, I prefer listing the arrays underneath one and other as I feel this helps with readability and generally just looks tidier - Especially, if the array is long.

Does anyone know if listing arrays/parameters have any performance 'ill effects' such as slowing down the page load speed etc?  As far as I can see, it is just a coder's preference.  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: This question isn't particularly to stackoverflows scope but the array structure is purely per coders preference. If there was any 'performance benefits', they'd be marginal. If speed is an issue, you'd be better off looking for actual bottle necks within your processing code as the array is purely defined. The performance effects come when handling that array data. (*i.e, looping, modifying, updating, etc*)

Comment: Thanks for your input Darren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code formatting has no effect on performance.

Even if you claim that a larger file takes longer to read, if you are using at least PHP 5.5 then PHP will use an opcode cache - it will cache how it parsed your files for subsequent requests, eliminating any formatting that you have in your file.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  As a side question, would this 'Opcode Cache' also eliminate white space, or is this something I would need to do myself?

Comment: Whitespace is eliminated. Opcode is auto-generated code that PHP is parsed into. Think of it like simplifying an equation. If you see something like `y = a * (342 / 684)` you can simplify it to `y = a / 2`. You get a very different equation that you created yourself, that does the same thing.